# Docker Postgress: connect ECONNREFUSED when running the application

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have a compose file that looks as follows:

```bash
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgresdb:
    image: postgres:14.4-alpine
    container_name: pgsql
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0_init.sql
      # - $HOME/database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "8081:5432"
    expose:
      - "8081"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: todos
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: postgresdb
    networks:
      - internalnet

  nodeapp:
    container_name: server
    build: .
    image: nodeapp:1.0
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    expose:
      - "3002"
    environment:
      DB_HOST: postgresdb
      DB_PORT: 8081
      DB_USER: "admin"
      DB_PASSWORD: "password"
      DB_NAME: todos
      DB_CONNECTION_LIMIT: 20
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: nodeapp
      PORT: 3002
    depends_on:
      - postgresdb
    networks:
      - internalnet

networks:
  internalnet:
    driver: bridge
```

When i run the `compose up -d`  command the `ps` command here is what i am getting:

```bash
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS         PORTS                              NAMES
53a12ab5a9ae   nodeapp:1.0            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   12 seconds ago   Up 5 seconds   0.0.0.0:3002->3002/tcp             server
98cda5442cb0   postgres:14.4-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 seconds ago   Up 8 seconds   8081/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->5432/tcp   pgsql
```

To me this looks okay. But now when i try to send request to the server I'm getting an error saying:

```bash
"connect ECONNREFUSED 192.*.*.*:8081"
```

I don't know why my application is failing to connect to `postgres` of which they are on the same network.

Comment: The standard PostgreSQL port is 5432, and you need to use that in your application's connection information.  Connections between containers always use the "standard" ports; they don't need `ports:` and they ignore them if present.

Comment: (The `expose:` directive is obsolete and does nothing, and you can remove it.  Its effect would be a _container_ port but the image will already `EXPOSE 5432`, were that to have an effect.  If you want to trim down the file a little more you can also delete the `networks:` and `container_name:` sections without changing anything else.)